# Running Azure Mobile Server project locally

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, model-view-controller, azure-mobile-services

I'm running an Azure Mobile Server project locally with a local SQL Database.
I started from the Quickstart project, but as soon as I change the Entity to something more complex, I get this error with my migration:

**"Cannot create more than one clustered index on table..."**

Even with the correct schema I get this other error:

**"Automatic migrations that affect the location of the migrations history system table (such as default schema changes) are not supported. Please use code-based migrations for operations that affect the location of the migrations history system table."**

Comment: I'm getting this too, trying to run up an existing Azure Mobile Service on a new dev machine. All's well on the original developer's machine; but on mine `Update-Database -TargetMigration 201504231557345_InitialCreate -Verbose` fails with the clustered index message you describe

Comment: I was able to make it work by using in WebApiConfig: Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EntitiesContext, Configuration>()); and making an initial "Add-Migration Initial". After this, all modifications will be migrated automatically.

Comment: Sadly I'm not - I'll ask a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32141513/575530).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using migrations, there's a chance that EF is trying to create both the primary key and CreatedAt column as clustered indexes. If you tell the migration to use the Azure Mobile Services/Apps SqlGenerator, it should do the right thing.

See if my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214696/3516125) fixes the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an artifact of Entity Framework, the ORM that .NET Mobile Services use. It's recommended that you use Code First Migrations to address this issue. Mobile Services has a full guide which is kept up to date on how to enable code first migrations. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/

If you'd rather not deal with Code First Migrations, you can drop your database each time (not really a good idea for production purposes) or use the JavaScript backend.

Comment: Yes I tried that but I still get the "Cannot create more than one clustered index on table" error, and it seems I'm not the only one. First comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/

Comment: Yeah, it's possible something looks funny in the migrations. Look to see if more than one clustered index is being created and remove it in the migration file. This might be a bug on the SDK's part.

Comment: Can you verify that you are NOT using automatic migrations?  They behave quite differently, see "Adding a Code Based Migration" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx. Code Migrations creates a C# file in the migrations folder in your project--you can edit this and change clustered indexes.

Comment: I noticed the property CreatedAt of an EntityData object has Clustered set to true, is this a mistake on the SDK?

Comment: We're trying to determine where the error lies here. I was able to repro your issues, where a clustered index is being created on the "id" column and also the "createdAt" column. It should just be the "createdAt" column. A temporary work around is to create the schema yourself with that, and not use migrations until we have a better answer for you.

Comment: In AZM, CreatedAt should be in clustered index, not Id. Set Id as primary key with non clusteerd index.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT when you say "a temporary work around is to create the schema yourself" do you mean the database schema, i.e. the tables, indexes etc?

Comment: Check out @brettsam's answer above. It's not a bug that EntityData has a clustered index on CreatedAt, but there's no way to specific to EF that an index shouldn't be clustered. That's why the Mobile Apps/Services SqlGenerator needs to run. See EF feature request here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2163.