# How to initializing the code-first Entity Framework database in an Azure Mobile Services project

Tags: ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services, entity-framework-migrations

I am utterly confused by the use of Entity Frameworks code-first migrations within Azure Mobile Services.

I'm following the article [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/) with additional help from Stack Overflow answers, and have also read [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) and [Code First Migrations in Team Environments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501) and watched [Migrations - Under the Hood](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood).

In Visual Studio 2015 I make a new Azure Mobile Service, and then enable code-first migrations by going to the nuget Package Manager Console (PMC) and running `Enable-Migrations`. I then build and run the project. Then to make the database I create an initial migration with the PMC command `Add-Migration Initial` and apply it with the PMC command `Update-Database -Verbose -TargetMigration Initial`.

This fails with the error message

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table
>   'MobileService1.TodoItems'. Drop the existing clustered index
>   'PK_MobileService1.TodoItems' before creating another.

As I used the `Verbose` flag I can see the auto-generated SQL and indeed plugging that into a query and running it against a freshly minted database produces the same error because the primary key already provides a clustered index.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [MobileService1].[TodoItems] (
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max),
    [Complete] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Version] rowversion NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7),
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MobileService1.TodoItems] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CreatedAt] ON [MobileService1].[TodoItems]([CreatedAt])
```

However [the article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/) does warn me to make a change: replace `Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());` in `MobileService1.WebApiConfig.Register` with

```cs
var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

But after making that change I get exactly the same error when I run `Update-Database -Verbose -TargetMigration Initial` at the PMC.

Another suggestion, from Dominique Alexandre's comment on his question [Running Azure Mobile Server project locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953101/575530) is to instead replace `Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());` in `MobileService1.WebApiConfig.Register` with

```cs
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MobileServiceContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

But again I get exactly the same error.

What should I be using? Is there a simple way through Entity Frameworks code-first migrations as used in Azure Mobile Services?

Answer (score 12):

The specific error that you're seeing is due to the fact that EF assumes primary keys are also clustered indexes and there's no way to signal that this isn't the case. Things work when you perform automatic migrations because when the app starts, Mobile Services/Apps registers a custom SqlGenerator that removes the clustered index (along with a few other important things). This custom SqlGenerator isn't used by migrations by default.

However, you can tell your migration to use this same SqlGenerator by specifying it in the `Migrations\Configuration.cs` file:

```
// Mobile Services namespace:
// using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables

// Mobile Apps namespace:
// using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables;

---<snip>---

    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
    }
```

Give that a try. The resulting db should include the CreatedAt trigger and other SQL-specific settings that Mobile Services/Apps expects. Let me know if you bump into issues doing this and I can look further.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: This is now documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/#using-code-first-migrations-without-an-initializer

Comment: @lindydonna That link is broken, do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

After trying every solution I can find, , I found the magic is located in these lines (from the Quickstart project)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
               new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                   "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

(add to your context class)

This solved the clustered error problem.
(I'm working with Azure Mobile Apps not Mobile Services)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and I also get this error when using **Update-Database** in PMC.

I'm using Azure Mobile Apps, not Services, but it's the same Entity-Data.

Starting from an empty table, what works for me is just having an **Initial Migration** file, a **Configuration.cs** and the **MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion** bit. Then you can just run the application with **F5** instead of **Update-Database**.

It should create your schema along with your seed.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid automatic migrations so that I can be certain any live data is secure. But thanks. It is odd that UpdateDatabaseToLatest version succeeds where Update-Database fails - you'd think they ran the same code.

Comment: Chris Anderson-MSFT said they know about this problem. I guess they'll fix this soon.

Comment: Thanks Dominique. And I wonder If I should just go for your MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion code. [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/) suggests that a similar call, `var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
migrator.Update();` will preserve data.

Comment: That line didn't work in my case, that's why I'm using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, it keeps my data.