# Add related database entry in Azure Mobile Services controller

Tags: entity-framework, azure-mobile-services

In my Azure Mobile Service I have a controller class `UserController : TableController<User>` and in it is a get method:

```cs
// GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public SingleResult<User> GetUser(string id)
{
    return Lookup(id);
}
```

I want to record each time a user is accessed and so I add a simple type to the model:

```cs
public class UserVisit : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData
{
    public string VisitingUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfVisit { get; set; }
}
```

and include the property `public DbSet<UserVisit> UserVisits { get; set; }` in my `VCollectAPIContext : DbContext` class (and update the database with a code-first migration).

To add a UserVisit to the database when a user id is queried I change my controller method to

```cs
// GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public async Task<SingleResult<User>> GetUser(string id)
{
    var userVisit = new UserVisit { VisitingUser = id, TimeOfVisit = DateTime.UtcNow };
    context.UserVisits.Add(userVisit);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Lookup(id);
}
```

But the `SaveChangesAsync` fails with a `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`. Digging around in the exception's `EntityValidationErrors` property I find that the problem is "The Id field is required."

That's a little odd. The Id field is one of the properties in the base-class `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData` that I would expect to be added automatically on insert. No matter, I can add it and several of the other base-class's properties thus:

```cs
// GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public async Task<SingleResult<User>> GetUser(string id)
{
    var userVisit = new UserVisit { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Deleted = false, VisitingUser = id, TimeOfVisit = DateTime.UtcNow, CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now };
    context.UserVisits.Add(userVisit);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Lookup(id);
}
```

This time I get a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` because we "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedAt'". It was not null in the call to `Add`. So `CreatedAt` has been set to null somewhere outside my code and then the insert fails as a result!

I also tried setting up an `EntityDomainManager<UserVisit> userVisitDomainManager;` instance variable in the controller's initializer, and then rewriting my controller get method as

```cs
// GET tables/User/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public async Task<SingleResult<User>> GetUser(string id)
{
    var userVisit = new UserVisit { VisitingUser = id, TimeOfVisit = DateTime.UtcNow };
    await userVisitDomainManager.InsertAsync(userVisit);
    return Lookup(id);
}
```

That fails with the same message, "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedAt'"

How should I perform the seemingly simple task of inserting a related data item within my controller method?

Comment: What does the UserVisit table look like in the database?  I wonder if the problem is that the mobile services SqlGenerator did not run. The behavior you're describing of context.UserVisits.Add() is very strange though!

Comment: Try logging the SQL statements that are produced: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#Log

Answer (score 2):

The solution is likely similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214696/3516125). I'm guessing that your migration is not using the Mobile Services SqlGenerator so some of the custom SQL settings aren't getting applied. What that means is that:

- Id doesn't get a default value of NEWID() -- this explains your "Id field is required" error.
- CreatedAt doesn't get a default value of SYSUTCDATETIME() -- this, combined with the [DatabaseGenerated] attribute on EntityData.CreatedAt, explains the "NULL CreatedAt" error.

Try updating your migration according to the link above and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Brett - I'll try that. How would I force my migration to use the Mobile Services SqlGenerator?

Comment: Check out the link in my answer above -- it shows you this: `SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());`

Comment: I have not had a chance to check this as I'm mired in other server errors that I need to navigate through but I'll award the bounty anyway before it times out as this looks hopeful.

Comment: FYI, we've now documented this here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/#using-code-first-migrations-without-an-initializer

Comment: Now I get a `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException` when trying to save a new UserVisit to the database

Comment: Digging into the DbEntityValidationException I find the error Property: Id Error: The Id field is required so this is the same problem as before I added the `SetSqlGenerator`

Comment: Some questions: Is the migration adding this table as a new table or is it modifying an existing table? If you look at the default value of the Id column in your database (using Sql Management Studio or similar), does it have a value of NEWID()? 

The SqlGenerator will only work properly on table creation so I'm wondering if the custom actions are being skipped in your case.

Comment: Thanks Brett. It is a new table and the Id does have the default value newid() set (and CreatedAt has sysutcdatetime())

Comment: It sounds like EF is actually preventing the insert. Try setting Id yourself now with something like `Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`. This is actually how the EntityDomainManager handles calls to InsertAsync. But since you're not going through the EntityDomainManager for this tracking table, you'll need to set Id yourself. You should not get the CreatedAt exception anymore now that your database looks to have the correct default value there.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem of "**The Id field is required**" following **[brettsam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332740/2476450)**'s instructions.

Add this in your model:

```cs
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
public new string Id { get; set; }
```

It will auto generate a GUID when you add an entity.

Comment: That looks wrong. As mentioned in the question my model classes inherit from [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.entitydata.aspx) which provides the `Id` property (amongst other things). Surely that generates the GUID?

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't generate a GUID in my tests when I had an initial migration done with SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());

Comment: Thanks Dominique, that's useful. I think when I'm overriding SDK methods because they fail it's time to question using the SDK. I'm currently exploring rewriting my server-side code in ASP.Net API 2 with Entity Frameworks but without Azure Mobile Services.

Comment: The Azure SDK for mobile phones works great, but I'm not even using Azure in my case, just the Table Controller in my self-hosted API. Maybe this SDK should be named something else, since it's so useful.

Comment: That's really interesting - I'm going to check that out as a way to lessen the amount of code we write in EF