# Azure Mobile EntityData ClusteredIndex Exception

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've got a simple system that is in development stage and has few entities that some have relations with others and some stand by their own.
We're are going to use azure mobile services to be able to read data from a mobile app. For that we need to make our domain models inherit from EntityData.
When the EntityFramework initializer kicks in, I get this exception for this little relationless class:

> Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.ChaveDeRegistro'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.ChaveDeRegistro' before creating another.

Heres the class:

```
public class ChaveDeRegistro : EntityData
{
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public Guid Chave { get; set; }
    public bool Valida { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
}
```

I found the anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141513/how-to-initializing-the-code-first-entity-framework-database-in-an-azure-mobile/32214696#32214696) but its for a migration issue. It explains whats causing my exception, but doesnt give a solution for my case(only initializing it, no real data is used so far).

Baseline: EF assume that PK's are clustered indexes. And as in EntityData class theres a PK, and a CreatedAt field with a Clustered Index Annotation, it throws this exception. I need to be able to set the SQLGenerator to the one MobileService uses to make it solve this.

How on earth can I make the initilizer, for once, create the database for my entities using EntityData?
Whats the catch here? Im almost giving up Azure for a thousand problems with this EntityClass and very little, poor and superficial documentation.

Comment: Couple of questions: (a) What DbInitializer are you using? (b) Does this table exist in SQL already or is it starting from scratch?

Comment: Its starting everytime since im doing DropCreateAlways. The application isnt on production yet, so no real data in it.
But anyway, since I asked this I've made some progress. I've found this guide(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#install-sdk) that shows how to adapt a existing WEB API to be able to deal with Azure mobile clients.It worked. All entities are inheriting from EntityData, it compiles, creates the DB but when seeding starts it throws "The Id field is required" for all entities.

Comment: It seems like making my API mobile ready didnt got the DB to be generated correctly.
A few more points: My context is not in same project as my API, its on other data access layer project and last but not least and very important: as I started the project without knowing the Azure mobile restrictions I also used ASP.net Identity for authentication, making my User class inherit from IdentityUser, so I had to manually add the properties(excluding Id) from EntityData to my User class.

Comment: How are you configuring your Mobile App? It sounds likely that the `EntityTableSqlGenerator` that is used by Mobile Apps tables isn't properly registered with EF. Are you setting it up like this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/samples/SampleApp/App_Start/Startup.MobileApp.cs#L31

Comment: Heres my config: var config = new HttpConfiguration(); new MobileAppConfiguration().UseDefaultConfiguration().ApplyTo(config); WebApiConfig.Register(config); app.UseWebApi(config);

Also, as Im using Identity, my context inherits from IdentityDbContext<User>. Couldnt that have somethign to do with it? Im considering anything at this point.

Comment: I tried something couple days ago. I created a whole new Mobile App project form the Azure SDK templante in VS and added the ASP Identity Nuget packages. Changed the EF Context from to inherit to IdentityDbContext<> typed on a User class witch in turn inherit from IdentityUser. When I run and try to do a GET on the ToDoItems list, it throws exception when it tries to generate the DB saying the classes from Identity like IdentityUserRoles dont have a PK. That might be the Mobile SQLGenerator messing up with Identity tables. I thinks thats the problem.